# "bundle install" error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I recently changed my ubuntu to Linux mint so i need to re-install my gems but it gives me this error....

**Steps i have done**

- Generated pub/private keys and added to github.
- re run command "bundle install" but its not working.

---

```
Fetching git://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma.git
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

Retrying git fetch --force --quiet --tags 


"/home/asad/.bundler/cache/git/capistrano-puma-e90ae8bdcca081264c0ff67caa1d11e89f7a01e0" due to error (2/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git fetch --force --quiet --tags "/home/asad/.bundler/cache/git/capistrano-puma-e90ae8bdcca081264c0ff67caa1d11e89f7a01e0"` in directory /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bundler/gems/capistrano-puma-7748efb9a53d has failed.
        If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/home/asad/.bundler/cache/git/capistrano-puma-e90ae8bdcca081264c0ff67caa1d11e89f7a01e0'
        error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

        Retrying git fetch --force --quiet --tags "/home/asad/.bundler/cache/git/capistrano-puma-e90ae8bdcca081264c0ff67caa1d11e89f7a01e0" due to error (3/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git fetch --force --quiet --tags "/home/asad/.bundler/cache/git/capistrano-puma-e90ae8bdcca081264c0ff67caa1d11e89f7a01e0"` in directory /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bundler/gems/capistrano-puma-7748efb9a53d has failed.
        If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/home/asad/.bundler/cache/git/capistrano-puma-e90ae8bdcca081264c0ff67caa1d11e89f7a01e0'
        error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

        Git error: command `git fetch --force --quiet --tags "/home/asad/.bundler/cache/git/capistrano-puma-e90ae8bdcca081264c0ff67caa1d11e89f7a01e0"` in directory
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bundler/gems/capistrano-puma-7748efb9a53d has failed.
        If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/home/asad/.bundler/cache/git/capistrano-puma-e90ae8bdcca081264c0ff67caa1d11e89f7a01e0'
```

Comment: try changing gem `'capistrano3-puma', github: "seuros/capistrano-puma"` to `gem 'capistrano3-puma' , group: :development`. It should work

Answer (score 16):

If you are using `rvm`, From the command line run:

```
~> rvm fix-permissions
```

This solved that kind of error for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
bundle exec bundle install
```

worked for me. I made the mistake of installing ruby when I was logged in as root so I have to do this now until I fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue when upgrading bundler ... it turns out the cache directory in the bundle system install location was causing the issue .. purging this completely fixed the problem - this was on OSX, not using RVM, but the standard OSX ruby on 10.10.3

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using `rbenv` and faced the same issue while `bundle install`.

### Reason

while cloning the `rbenv` from its repo I unknowigly used `sudo` like

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

This makes `sudo` the owner of the directory and other users have no permission to access the repo.

### Solution

> Don't know if it is the best way to solve this issue; sorry

I changed the permission of the directory `~/.rbenv`

```
sudo chmod 777 ~/.rbenv/**
```